# question about regular mapping in elementary differential geometry by Oneill

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking at Oneill elementary differential geometry section 4.2 Patch Computations.

In example 2.4, parametrization of a surface of revolution, it says

Suppose that $M$ is obtained by revolving a curve $C$ in the upper half of the xy plane about the x axis. Now let
$$a(u)=(g(u), h(u), 0)$$
be a parametrization of $C$. Note that $h>0$. Let
$$x(u, v)=\left(g(u), h(u)\cos v, h(u)\sin v\right)$$.

Then $x_u$ and $x_v$ are linearly independent.

However, my computation shows that when $g'(u)=h'(u)=0$, $x_u$ and $x_v$ are linearly dependent.

Why did the book assume that the parametrization of $C$ always have nonzero velocity?
Where did it make such assumption?

Comment: He is referring to a *regular* parametrization.

Comment: I looked at the book and it did not assume that the parametrization is regular.

Comment: That's an important lesson in reading math books: sometimes you have to read *between* the lines :-)

Comment: do you have that book? could you tell me where it suggests regular curve? I cannot find that and the book talked a lot about irregular curves.

Comment: I don't have access to page 135 where example 1.5 starts. Does he say C is regular there?

Comment: I double checked Example 1.5. It does not say that $C$ is regular. It only says 'Let C be a curve in a plane A $\subset$     $R^3$'

Comment: What does it say about its parametrisation?

Comment: it only says ' if the profile curve is C: $f(x,y)=c$'. No regularity on the plane curve C. I am confused.

Comment: By the implicit function theorem if the gradient of $f$ is nonzero then locally the level curve admits a regular parametrisation. This is what he is relying on here.

Comment: why can he assume that the gradient of f is nonzero?

Comment: Without such an assumption you can't guarantee that the level curve will be smooth.

Comment: This makes sense!